How can I make a const char array function be preferred before a const char* function when resolving function names?
A string literal when passed to a function will be deduced to be first a const char (&)[] array first, and then if not function is suitable it will decay to a const char*. So I thought that the following would work, however the const char* function is still being called:
#include <iostream>
//
struct MyString
{
    MyString() { }
    template <typename ...Ts>
    MyString(Ts&& ... args)
    {
        append(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    void append(const char* str)
    {
        /* NOW STRING LENGTH WILL HAVE TO BE CALLED ON THIS */
        std::cout << "append const char* called\n";
    }
    template <int N>
    void append(const char(&arr)[N])
    {
        /* I KNOW THE SIZE OF THE STRING HERE */
        std::cout << "append arr[N] called \n";

    }

};
int main()
{
    MyString s;// { "Hello" };
    s.append("Imagine some really long string");
}

I guess this is because non-template functions are preferred first. Can I make it prefer the array one without deleting the const char* ?

Make both append functions template functions, then use enable_if to SFINAE each one to its particular case.

@JeJo The option to pass a non-literal string.

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char const*>>> void append(T str) and template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char const>>> void append(T(&arr)[N]).  (Or use C++20 concepts.  I'm on C++17.)

FWIW your first assumption is wrong, no one will be preferred, the call would be ambiguous

@Eljay I posted an answer following your good suggestion, since I saw you do seem to be interestded in posting one.

Following the suggestion in @Eljay's comment:
You can make both overloads templated, and then use SFINAE with std::enable_if to force the compiler to choose the proper overload:
#include <iostream>

struct MyString
{
    MyString() { }
    template <typename ...Ts>
    MyString(Ts&& ... args)
    {
        append(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char const*>>> 
    void append([[maybe_unused]] T str)
    {
        std::cout << "append const char* called\n";
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char const>>> 
    void append([[maybe_unused]] T(&arr)[N])
    {
        std::cout << "append arr[N] called \n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString s;
    s.append("Imagine some really long string");
    s.append(static_cast<char const*>("Imagine some really long string"));
}

Output:
append arr[N] called
append const char* called

Live demo
